# Transform XML "yes/no" string to boolean

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

A legacy XML feed we want to consume (it's coupled to a specific database and has no XSD) emits "Y" or "N" as truth values. We are creating an XSD and auto-generating C# classes from this, with some transforms to make things neater.

So if I have fields like `<IsFed>Y</IsFed>` on an object, how can I transform these using XSLT so something that would validate against `xsd:boolean`?

I'm interested in two approaches:

1. Explicitly listing each field to be transformed
2. Automatically detecting every such yes/no field (I realise this could have errors)

Sample XML might look like this:

```
<Animal type="hamster">
 <IsFed>Y</IsFed>
 <Name>Gerald</Name>
</Animal>
<Animal type="cow">
 <IsFed>N</IsFed>
 <Name>acv4445-7</Name>
</Animal>
```

And it should come out like:

```
<Animal type="hamster">
 <IsFed>true</IsFed>
 <Name>Gerald</Name>
</Animal>
<Animal type="cow">
 <IsFed>false</IsFed>
 <Name>acv4445-7</Name>
</Animal>
```

Comment: Seems like a trivial XSL transform since you say you're already doing a transformation.  What is the question?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm asking how to do the transform since I've never used XLST before. I ask both ways to try and learn a bit more about XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Explicitly listing each field to be transformed

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- list every boolean element here -->
<xsl:template match="IsFed | HasShelter | etc.  ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=".='Y'"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> 2. Automatically detecting every such yes/no field (I realise this could have errors)

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[.='Y']">true</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[.='N']">false</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting little problem.  Here's one possible solution for XSLT 2 (XSLT 1 solution down below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Is') and matches(text(),'[YN]')]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="if (.='Y') then 'true' else 'false'"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is an identity transform plus a template matching the text of any element whose name starts with `Is` and whose value is `Y` or `N`, which it replaces with `true` or `false`.  It does not affect an element whose name starts with `Is` whose value is not `Y` or `N`.

Here's the same thing for XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(),1,2) = 'Is' and (text() = 'Y' or text() = 'N')]/text()">
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test=". = 'Y'">true</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```